# How to create user defined type template class object C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am struggling with allowing user to select data type template will be created as.
Since template type must be defined on compile, I must specify data type template will use eg(string,int, so on), but that means I cannot change it latter on, from lets say string to int even if my template supports it, because template class object was declared as string.
My class declaration below:

```
template <class T>
class MyHashTable
{
public:
    string deleted="deleted";
    unsigned short tableSize;
    // array of vectors, hash table container
    vector<T>* myTable;
    vector<T>* deletionTable;

    MyHashTable(unsigned short tableSize) : myTable(new vector<T>[tableSize]),  deletionTable(new vector<T>[tableSize])
    {
        this->tableSize=tableSize;
    }
```

object declaration outside class

```
    MyHashTable <string>* myChainedTable=NULL ;
    string tableType;
```

object initialization

```
 if (myChainedTable)
{
    delete myChainedTable;
    myChainedTable=NULL;
}
getType();
if (!myChainedTable)
{
    if (tableType=="string")
        myChainedTable= new MyHashTable<string>(length);  
    if (tableType=="char")
        MyHashTable<char> myChainedTable(length);  // no difference with or without using new keyword
    if (tableType=="double")
        MyHashTable<double> myChainedTable(length);
    if (tableType=="float")
        MyHashTable<float> myChainedTable(length);
    if (tableType=="int")
        MyHashTable<int> myChainedTable(length);

    cout<<tableType<<" table of size "<< length<<" created"<<endl;
```

I attempted passing class object to functions instead of having it as global variable, but couldnt get it work either.

What I really need is single template object that can have: int,string,char,double,float types, I have 3 functions that need to have access to template class object, and having 5 different objects and 200 lines of if statements for each situation sounds like worst possible solution.
I been stuck on this for a while and just cant figure out how to do it and any help will be appreciated.

```
void getType()
{
    cout<<"Enter table type, types available: int, char, float, double, string.\n";
    tableType=getInput();
    while((tableType != "int")&&(tableType !="float")&&(tableType !="double")&&(tableType!="char")&&(tableType !="string"))
    {
        cout<<"Invalid type, please try again "<<endl;;
        tableType=getInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `tableType`? This doesn't sound like a job for templates.

Comment: @Jefffrey updated my question, initially had tableType as return statement, changed to global variable while doing some changes, didnt help much though.

Comment: The codifitional definitions ar doomed to fail.  Each is local to the if statement and gets fogotten as soon as you exit the if !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is at the boarder between templates and variants.

The template is compile time.  So you have to choose at compile time the type you want for your object.  Your conditional approach can't work (see comments to question).

On the other side, you seem to need a dynamic choice of type at runtime.

**If you want to go on on template way: (edit based on comments)**

You'd need to have all the templates inherit from a single polymorphic base class (one common interface with virtual functions). Example:

```
class MyHashBase  // common base class for all templates
{
public:
    virtual void addElement(void *ptrelem) = 0;   // adding an element must be implemented by template. With void* since future template type unknown from base class
    virtual void displayAll() = 0; 
};
```

The templates would need then implement the virtual functions:

```
template <class T>
class MyHashTable : public MyHashBase
{
public:
    unsigned short tableSize;
    vector<T>* myTable;        // I leave it as it is, but you could implement these as vector<T> instead of vector<T>* 
    vector<T>* deletionTable;

    MyHashTable(unsigned short tableSize) : myTable(new vector<T>[tableSize]), deletionTable(new vector<T>[tableSize]), tableSize(tableSize)
    { }
    void addElement(void* ptrelem)
    {   myTable->push_back(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptrelem));  }   // reinterpret the void* of the common interface as a T* 
    void displayAll()
    { copy(myTable->begin(), myTable->end(), ostream_iterator<T>(cout, "\n")); }
};
```

You could then have your `myChainedTable` be a pointer to the common base type,  and intialise this pointer in the way you did with the string case (i.e. using `new`).

```
MyHashBase *myChainedTable = nullptr; 
//...
if (tableType == "string")
    myChainedTable = new MyHashTable<string>(length);
else if (tableType == "double")
    myChainedTable = new MyHashTable<double>(length);
//...
```

You could then use the common API, for example if `tableType` is `"double"`:

```
double d1 = 3.1415, d2 = 1.4142; 
myChainedTable->addElement(&d1);   // ATTENTION: you must ensure to provide pointer to the correct data type
myChainedTable->addElement(&d2);
myChainedTable->displayAll();
```

You'll certainly have a coupe of if required in the calling code, but you could reduce them to minimum by carefully designing the base class (for example, you could add a virtual clone function, to duplicate the data without need to know the type by the caller).

However, using a single signature for the common functions of the base class is cumbersome.  To make the virtualisation possible you need to pass parameters through `void*` pointer which is not so nice and rather error prone.

**Alternate way with variants**

You could also use **[boost variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html)** which are meant for managing objects with dynamic definition of types.

In this case you would not need template for your own data structure.  You would create a `MyHashTable` with elements of type `boost::variant< int, std::string, ... >`.

You could then access to the right value of the object if you know its type (as in your `myChainedTable`) by using:  `boost::get<int> (element)` (or `boost::get<string>()`, ...).

If you don't know the type on an element you could use the concept of "visitor" to chose automatically the appropriate function to exectue depending on the type.

**Edit:  alternate way with unions:**

If you're not allowed to use variants another alternative could be use a `union`. I don't know the topic of you rassignment, but you have the choice whether you use a union to define the elements (like the variants, without templates) or to use a template type as you did, but define `myChainedTable` to be a union of pointers to the different template instantiations.   But yes,  it requires a lot of `if`s...

Comment: Duh ;/ I hoped I just missed something obvious, variants sounds good, but I cant use boost.Union looks just like fancy array and I still would need to have bunch of if statements to know which one to call, but better than nothing I suppose. Could you give me an example how pointer approach would look? I am already calling my class using pointers since my original declaration is a pointer, but im not sure how to make one pointer into 5 objects

Comment: I made an edit with code to make clera how this option could work.

Comment: Cheers, I gave in and just created 5 different objects and huge if statement filled function to handle switching between them, if I'll have time I'll try to change it using your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are resolved at compile time. Your container type is resolved at runtime. Templates are clearly not the solution here. The first thing that comes to my mind is a combination of `boost::any` and `std::vector` instead.

Comment: well this is an assignment, and I cannot use c++14 (templated variables would help me), cannot use c++11 either and I wont dream using boost ;/, templating was supposed to be easy part of assignment, but I been stuck for a day on it now,well templating is done, everything works if I define single type, but user needs to be able to change data types on the fly(deleting current object) and only one object needs to exist. There must be a way for it, am I just overcomplicating this?